# Finding $E[Z]$ and $P\left(\sqrt Z\le \frac32\right)$ where $Z=\min(X_1,X_2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Let $X_{1},X_{2} $ be independent and $X_{1},X_{2}  \sim U(1,6)$, $Z= \min(X_{1},X_{2})$, $ T = \sqrt{Z}$. Find $EZ$ and $P(T \le \frac{3}{2})$.

What I tried is the following : I took a  geometric approach since I don't see a Continuous Random Variables approach with functions. So if out first point lands on the point $a$ then the second point should be  in the interrval $6-a$, so our function is $Z = a(6-a)$ and then to find $EZ$ I will find the integral $$\int_{1}^{6} a^2(6-a) \,da$$

I am not sure if this is this is the way to solve it.

Comment: The value of that integral is over $100$, which is a sign that the method isn't correct (since $Z$ is never larger than $6$). Also, if the intention is for $X_1$ and $X_2$ to be independent, that needs to be specified.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will edit that they are.

Comment: By [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) theorem, $E[\min(X_1,X_2)]=\iint \min(x,y)f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ where $f_{X_1,X_2}$ is the pdf of $(X_1,X_2)$.

Comment: $Z$ is a real non-negative random variable.  If you find its CDF you can get the CDF of $T$ very easily.  Also $E[Z]$ equals the integral over the complementary CDF of Z.  There's no need for densities.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint about the minimum of two random variables to get you started.

For any real-valued random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, let $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$ be their cumulative distribution functions, so that $1-F_1(t)$ is the probability that $X_1>t$ and similarly for $1-F_2(t)$. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then the probability that both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are greater than $t$) is the product of these probabilities $(1-F_1(t))(1-F_2(t))$, and hence the probability that at least one of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is at most $t$ equals $1-(1-F_1(t))(1-F_2(t))$. This is therefore the cumulative distribution function of $\min\{X_1,X_2\}$.

In our case, we have $F_1(t)=F_2(t)=\tfrac15(t-1)$ (restricted to the interval $[1,6]$ of course). Therefore the cumulative distribution function of $Z = \min\{X_1,X_2\}$ is
$$
1-\big(1-\tfrac15(t-1)\big)\big(1-\tfrac15(t-1)\big) = \tfrac1{25}(-t^2 + 12 t -11),
$$
and its density function is therefore the derivative, which is $\tfrac2{25}(-t+6)$.

Comment: How did you deduce that $F_{1}=\frac{t-1}{5}$ , Shouldn't the probability be $\frac{t}{5}$ since we seek a point greater than t in the interval 5?

Comment: I recommend reviewing the concepts of the density function and the cumulative distribution function of a uniform distribution. It's totally fine to need to look at those items again; I just want to emphasize that being solid on those items is a prerequisite for working on more advanced problems like the one in the OP.

Comment: oh yes , the probability to pick a point in the interval [1;t] from [1;6] is just t-1/6-1 and the inverse statement is 1 minus the probability! now I have to find T I have to find $F_{Z}(x)$ and calculate the integral with the restrictions